# New project dialog does not show up, running Kubuntu 14.04

Tags: mavensmate

Installed sublime3 and then mavensmate package. I have v4.0.5, but when I try to create a new project it just gets stuck in 'handling requested operation'. What should I do to resolve this issue ?

Comment: Could you see if there are any error messages in the console logs (View-> View Console)?

Comment: That's the odd part where it is not even showing an error in the console. It just shows the command that mavensmate runs and than nothing

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to configure your default browser for handling HTML files. MavensMate's UIs are all html files so you need the correct file association to handle them.

Comment: I just checked my default browser is set as chrome on the laptop. Checked in System Settings -> Default Applications -> Web Browser. Tried to run it again but does not work

Comment: @MunisQuadri, could you try creating a blank html file and double clicking it? This is a long shot but it is the only idea I have.

Comment: Just did, Chrome is opening it. Maybe I should try putting Firefox as the default browser and see if it works

Comment: Setting up Mozilla as default browser is also not working